# Minimax Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, minimax

ok my problem has changed my problem now is that im trying to use the minimax algorithm like that website explains http://neverstopbuilding.com/minimax
and it gives me this error: "Argument out of range exception"
why is it happening i cant tell why the exception happens
this is what i did:

```
 int MiniMax(Seed[,] board, Seed currPlayer)
{
    if (checkBoard1(this.board) != -1) return score();
    List<int> scores = new List<int>();
    List<Vector2> moves = generateMoves();

    for (int i = 0; i < moves.Count; i++)
    {
        if (currPlayer == Seed.NOUGHT)
            currPlayer = Seed.CROSS;
        else
            currPlayer = Seed.NOUGHT;

        Seed[,] possibleBoard = getPossibleBoard(moves[i]);
        scores.Add(MiniMax(possibleBoard, currPlayer));
    }
    if(currPlayer == Seed.NOUGHT)
    {
        int max_score_index = getMaxIndexFromList(scores);
        choice = (Vector2)moves[max_score_index];
        return scores[max_score_index];
    }
    else
    {
        int min_score_index = getMinIndexFromList(scores);
        choice = (Vector2)moves[min_score_index];
        return scores[min_score_index];
    }
}
int getMinIndexFromList(List<int> list)
{
    int min = list[0], minIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (list[i] < min)
        {
            min = list[i];
            minIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return minIndex;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `Pair<int, int>`?

Comment: Are you asking how to change the return type of `int minimax(Seed[,] board, Seed currPlayer)` method? If so just replace int with Vector2 and change the body of the method to return a Vector2 instead of int.

Comment: Feels like everything is a `Seed` nowadays.

Comment: yeah i know how to turn it to return Vector2<x,y> the problem is i dont know if the function is right and if it's right even if i get the hioghest score how i can i relate it to the right move

Comment: It might be useful to rephrase and expand your question, you asked in your question how to change the return type, but in your comment you say that isn't actually what you care about. Could you explain what you are actually trying to figure out and what the problem with your current code is?